# How to check to see if a model array's contents are contained within another array's contents with duplicates and without a particular order

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a way to confirm if the contents of modelArray are present in array1-3. I am not checking for the order, just if the contents of modelArray are contained in the tested arrays including accounting for duplicates items (two 2's in modelArray so should return true if arrays being tested have at least two 2's).

Help would be much appreciated. I am just trying to learn and perhaps to see if I may test this simply to see if a shopper's cart contains the necessary items for a bundle (a bundle that needs two of an item to qualify, hence the duplicate 2's in the modelArray).

I've looked through stackoverflow and tried array_intersect() and array_diff(). However, I require assistance for the custom use case below.

`````
$modelArray = array(1,2,2,3,4); // the two 2's are intentional

$array1 = array(1,2,3,4); // should return False

$array2 = array(1,2,3,4,2,5,6,7,8); //should return True

$array3 = array(1,4,9,5); // should return False

function containsModel () {

//return if True or False
}

?>````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the arrays and check using [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) if the difference of the arrays is not an empty array:

```
function containsModel ($array) {

    $items = array(
    array(1,2,3,4),
    array(1,2,3,4,2,5,6,7,8),
    array(1,4,9,5)
    );

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if (!empty(array_diff($array, $item))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

$modelArray = array(1,2,2,3,4);

$res = containsModel($modelArray);
var_dump($res);
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/EAGIQ)

Comment: where is the function grabbing the modelArray to compare with the other arrays?

Comment: I'm still testing it. I had this before: 
`$cartWithBundle = array(1,2,3,4,2,4); //should return True
$cartWithoutBundle = array(1,4,3,4); // should return False

function containsModel ($array) {
    $bundleArray = array(1,2,2,3,4); // the two 2's are intentional
    return count(array_unique($bundleArray)) !== count($array);
}`

I am still trying to understand what is going on in your demo. Forgive me, I'm new to PHP. I'm having a hard time trying to make the var_dumps a variable.

Comment: No problem, I think I misunderstood your question the first time. What happens now is that you have a model which is an array of values and you want to check if all the other arrays contain those values right? So what you might do is create a collection of all those arrays (`$array1`, `$array2`, `$array3`) and loop that collection using a `foreach` checking if each array contains all values of the model. If one of the arrays in the collection does not contain all values of the model, then return false. If all pass, return true.

Comment: If you have a hard time trying to make the var_dumps a variable, take a look at [var_export](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

Comment: Thank you! You've been the nicest and most helpful person on SO. Is there anyway you could help me variablize the output of my function to True or False so I can use them for IF ELSE statements outside the function? I'm stuck with bool(False) returning nothing. I really just want the output of the function to help me set a $var = to True or False. After this,I promise not to bother you!
edit: sorry, just read your var_export comment. I'll play with it and see if it works out for me.

Comment: The function returns `true` or `false`, so in the example the variable `$res` is set to the return of the function which will be either true or false. See this example https://3v4l.org/f7j1Y and this example https://3v4l.org/3LivR